# how to mount permanently in Android

Tags: file-system, mount, auto-start

I've successfully mounted my router device's sdcard on '/mnt/routersd' as follows :

```
#!/system/bin/sh
su -c 'busybox mount -o remount,rw /'
su -c 'mkdir -p /mnt/routersd'
su -c 'busybox mount -o remount,ro /'

su -c 'busybox mount -t cifs //192.168.0.x/sdcard /mnt/routersd -v -o user=admin,pass=xxxxxx'
```

The issue is that the mounted folder is lost on every reboot; so, I need to manually execute my script after every reboot. What should I do to have this mounted directory, permanently?

Comment: I've found some articles using UUID and etc/fstab applicable for Linux editions different than Android; but I don't know how to apply it for Android.

Comment: Simply run a script every boot. Put it in `/system/etc/init.d` and you're done.

Comment: I'm using CM10.2.1 for ASUS Transformer Pad TF700T ; /system/etc/init.d exists but seems that doesn't support auto-startup. No script is executed from there.

Comment: You could use helpers such as *Tasker* (run a script at boot_complete) or *Script Manager* for that.

Comment: I've heard about them. Preferably, I would like not to install new apps for that purpose. Is it possible !?